# PHP get path and all subpaths (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal

I have a hard-coded menu in Drupal (as it's too complex for the standard Menu system in Drupal).

I would like to be able to say: If this page is contained within the /about/ directory, apply the class "active", so that all new pages created within this directory automatically highlight the current section.

Currently I have:

```
$current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

<ul class="main">
  <li class="home"><a href="<?php echo $base_path?>">Home</a></li>
  <li class="about 
  <?php if ($current_page == "/xxxxxxx.com/dev/about/") 
  {
      echo "active";
  }
  ?>"><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li>
  <li class="services"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a></li>
  <li class="work"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Work</a></li>
  <li class="awards"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Awards</a></li>
  <li class="environment"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Environment</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a few variations of strpos and explode to get the right variable, but with no luck so far.

Thanks :)

Comment: What make you think that your menu is too advanced for Drupal to handle? There are a lot of modules that extend the menu system, in particular the primary menu. This is most likely the wrong way to go, reinventing the wheel.

Comment: agreed with googletorp -- our Drupal menu is far more complex than that. I don't see anything in the code you've supplied that can't be done easily with existing modules.

Comment: I agree it is almost definitely possible to do it within Drupal, however for my particular site and this particular menu it is just much simpler to hardcode it. Just because it CAN be updatable, doesn't mean it has to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Drupal or your URL scheme, but the task of checking whether `$current_page` contains "/about/" you can do with:

```
if (strpos($current_page, '/about') !== false) echo "active";
```

You should probably listen to googletorp though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. It's like [arg](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/arg) function, but parse real path.

```
function real_arg($index = NULL) {
  $ofset = strlen(base_path());
  $q = explode('?', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $ofset));
  $q = explode('/',  trim($q[0], '/'));

  return isset($index) ? $q[$index] : $q;
}
```

In your case:

```
if(real_arg(0) == 'about') echo 'active';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu api then theme your links to match what you want. You won't need to duplicate functionality that already exists. You'll acquire a skill you can reuse.

See:
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_item/6
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_item_link/6

It shouldn't take long and you'll remove a layer of workarounds.